# Can't check string value

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am trying to check a string value in if but it always is entering the else,
what Is wrong here? Thank you

```
public void alertBtn(View v){
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String value = text.getText().toString();
    String password="asd";
    if (value==password){

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Success")
            .setMessage("Correct Password")
            .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
            .show();
        }
    else
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Error")
        .setMessage("Wrong password")
        .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
        .show();



}
```

Comment: Please... don't use `==` to compare Strings. Please don't..

Comment: use equals() function

Comment: For those who answer, you might also want to give an explanation..... Specially when this question has been answered 1000 times.

Comment: What would you like me to explain? I am just trying to make a log in screen.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **==** operator will compare the references to the strings not the string themselves.

```
String value = text.getText().toString();
String password="asd";

if (value.equals(password))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` to compare strings

[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

```
 if (value.equals(password)){
```

Also move the initialization of editText to `onCreate`. There is no need to initialize edittext everytime on button click

```
  text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); // in onCreate
```

and declare `EditText text` as class member

Comment: Thank you a lot, is there any site where I can find basic commands?

Answer (score 1):

use equals() function

Try

```
if( value.equals(password) ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Use the `String.equals(String other)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator.

The function checks the actual contents of the string, the `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. Note that string constants are usually "interned" such that two constants with the same value can actually be compared with `==`, but it's better not to rely on that.